# Why would my Swagger.JSON related to a DTO not update based upon the definition in the API.XML file being update?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, visual-studio-2019, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET Core app and using Swashbuckle.ASP.NECore 5.5.1.

My DTO class is (I removed the XML Comments):

```
public class ArticleBankDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<ArticleTagDTO> ArticleTags;

    public List<ArticleDTO> Articles;

    public List<ArticleSourceDTO> Sources;

    private ArticleBankDTO() { }

    public ArticleBankDTO(int id, List<ArticleTagDTO> articleTags, List<ArticleDTO> articles, List<ArticleSourceDTO> sources)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));
        }


        ID = id;
        ArticleTags = articleTags ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(articleTags));
        Articles = articles ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(articles));
        Sources = sources ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sources));
    }
```

Inside the Get on my Controller I have:

```
            var result = await ControllerRepository.GetArticleBankAsync(articleBankdID);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<ArticleBankDTO>(result));
```

I look at my API.XML file generated for the ArticleBankDTO and it is:

[image]

In the Swagger.JSON it is reflected as:

[image]
[image]

And my Swagger UI is:
[image]

I have cleaned the solution and rebuilt the solution and the changes do not make it through to the SWagger.JSON.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

In my startup.cs I have in ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
                $"JobAssistOpenAPISpecification",
                new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
                {
                    Title = "ArticleBank API",
                    Version = "1",
                    Description = "Through this API you can access ArticleBank.",
                });

            var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);

            setupAction.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);
        });
```

Comment: Check your build configuration, you may be looking at the debug xml file while running in release or vice versa

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson No it isnt the debug xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue.  You need {get; set;} for all properties.  Once I did:

```
public List<ArticleTagDTO> ArticleTags {get; set;} 

public List<ArticleDTO> Articles {get; set;} 

public List<ArticleSourceDTO> Sources {get; set;}
```

Everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public async Task<List<ArticleBankDTO>> GetListAsync(EntityDto<int> input)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await ControllerRepository.GetArticleBankAsync(articleBankdID);
            return new List<ArticleBankDTO>(result.MapTo<List<ArticleBankDTO>>());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you comment on the code in your answer, it's not obvious what you have done or how this answers the question.